# How to simulate and debug PAYER_ACTION_REQUIRED?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

we are integrating the Paypal-API for Paypal-Checkout and came about the possebility that Paypal might return a PAYER_ACTION_REQUIRED-error (see https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-PAYER_ACTION_REQUIRED).

We now want to see if our understanding and implemented handling of this error is correct, but we couldn't find a way to provoke this error intentionally in the sandbox to debug our code. How is it done?

We tried to use a card-number from this page:
https://developer.paypal.com/tools/sandbox/card-testing/#rejection-triggers
and tried to use a "rejection trigger", but either we get "the name contains invalid characters"- or "the credit-card data is not valid"-messages, but the Paypal-Window is never leaved so none of these errors hits our code.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

See the guide for [integrating 3D Secure](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/advanced/customize/3d-secure/), which is what returns this status. It's particularly necessary for processing cards from Europe with an Advanced Credit and Debit Cards integration.

If you are using the Standard integration, you do not need to be concerned about 3DS as it's taken care of by PayPal.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately, it was not possible to use the standard integration in our shop-system. Thanks for your hint to 3D Secure, I tried to use some cards listed in https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/advanced/customize/3d-secure/test/, but the PAYER_ACTION_REQUIRED-error never occured so far.

Comment: The payments all just work in the sandbox, no matter which creditcard I use from the link above.

Comment: Make sure your integration is setting the SCA_REQUIRED. Try some other 3DS cards like 5232106671708398 , 5356660078288487 , 5356660030805261

Comment: This article also has information on when PAYER_CAPTURE_REQUIRED can be trigged for an overcapture case due to PSD 2 in Europe: https://www.paypal.com/us/smarthelp/article/FAQ4645

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I'm still not able to simulate a "PAYER_ACTION_REQUIRED". I tried your creditcard-numbers, but only got the message from paypal "we are not able to add your card". How do I set SCA_REQUIRED? Seraching in the Paypal-Docs I'm getting no hits for that.

Comment: I tried to overcapture as well, getting an authorization for 100€ and executing an payment for 200€, but the payment was accepted without any problem or error. Huh?!